# Definition of covariant derivative of a covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

If we have a connection $\nabla$ different than the Levi-Civita connection, and for a Riemannian metric $g$ and $\nabla$ this relation is valid:
\begin{align}
Zg(X,Y)=g(\nabla_{Z}X,Y)+g(X,\nabla^{*}_{Z}Y),
\end{align}
$\nabla^{*}$ is the dual connection of $\nabla$.
Does it make any sense to define a second order derivative as:
\begin{align}
\nabla\nabla^{*}_{X,Y}s=\nabla_{X}(\nabla^{*}_{Y}s)-\nabla_{\nabla^{*}_{X}Y}s?
\end{align}
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by dual connection?

Comment: It is just called the dual connection(with respect to g) if it satisfies the first equation I wrote.

Comment: Oh right. I guess it depends what you mean by "makes sense". Unless I'm making a silly mistake it's $C^\infty$-linear in $X$ and $Y$ (though the same could be said for such a construction using *any* two affine connections on the tangent bundle - the duality condition doesn't come in to it).

Comment: Yes, it is $C^{\infty}$ linear in $X$ and $Y$. I just wonder would it the definition above be correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we extend $\nabla$ and $\nabla^*$ to derivations of the tensor algebra via the Leibniz rule, then actually

$$
(\nabla \nabla^* s)(X,Y) = (\nabla_X\nabla^*s)(Y)=\nabla_X(\nabla^*s(Y)) - \nabla^* s(\nabla_XY) = \nabla_X (\nabla^*_Y s) - \nabla^*_{\nabla_X Y} s.
$$